# Prevent any user activity on website for specific period of time: javascript

Tags: javascript

I have made a website, something like a control panel that controls different devices connected to microcontroller (the website itself is hosted on microcontroller).

I encounter this problem: If user change state of some check box (you can think of them like on/off buttons) and immediately after that sends some other command, my system crashes. To avoid this I need to introduce delay that would disable user for clicking any other button on website for specific amount of time (in my case 5 seconds). I am using JavaScript to communicate http requests to/and from my microcontroller so I am looking for JavaScript based solution.

Hope I made myself clear and thank you for your help.

Comment: I think that the simpliest approach is to show a loading modal box sizing to whole window. And hide that modal box when finished request.

Comment: @Andy I am relatively new to JavaScript, so I am asking for logic behind solution not solution itself. I did googled this, but search results provides me with disable the right click on website (which is obviously not what I'm looking for). Because I am lacking of experience I am seeking for experienced user here to give me hint.

Comment: The moment when the user selects some option, show a overlay image(like the way Jquery shows the modal dialog pop-up) and use the setTimeout function to disable/remove that overlay after a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the post states the website itself is hosted on a micro-controller, jQuery may be inappropriate (storage constraints) for the answer. The general theme however is still the same. When a user changes an appropriate control show a modal div with a 'please wait' or some other message.

You don't mention the browser you want to target so I'm assuming a chrome or firefox version.

**CSS:**

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 1001;
    display: none;
}

.modal.active {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML** (Place this div somewhere in the root of body, and only once):

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <h3>Please wait...</h3>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// get your elements
var element = document.getElementById("myField");
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");

// opens the modal
function openModal() {
    modal.classList.add("active");
}

// closes the modal
function closeModal() {
    modal.classList.remove("active");
}

// opens the modal, then closes it after a timeout period
function openTemporaryModal(var timeout) {
    openModal();
    setTimeout(function() {
        closeModal();
    }, timeout);
}

// used as an event callback
function modalForFiveSeconds() {
    openTemporaryModal(5000);
}

// Attach the event callback to the element/event you want to open the modal:
element.addEventListener('change', modalForFiveSeconds);
```

**References:**

- [MDN: document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)
- [MDN: element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)
- [MDN: window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)
- [MDN: element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need to attached an EVENT to all of the checkboxes you have.

Something like this:

```
$.("input[type='checkbox']").change(disableScreen);
```

Create a div that would disable the screen

```
<div id="disablingDiv" ></div>
```

Then we have to create a new function called disableScreen.

```
function disableScreen() {
var $disablingDiv= $("#disablingDiv");
 $body.addClass("disablingDiv");
 window.setTimeout(function () {
    $body.removeClass("disablingDiv");   
 }, 5000);
}

 .disablingDiv
{
/* Do not display it on entry */
display: none; 

/* Display it on the layer with index 1001.
   Make sure this is the highest z-index value
   used by layers on that page */
z-index:1001;

/* make it cover the whole screen */
position: absolute; 
top: 0%; 
left: 0%; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 

/* make it white but fully transparent */
background-color: white; 
opacity:.00; 
filter: alpha(opacity=00); 
}
```

Hiding div solution was taken from "[Disable all page elements with transparent div](http://fczaja.blogspot.co.il/2009/02/disable-all-page-elements-with.html)"

Comment: Thank you for answer, although this is jquery I believe, I will try to adopt it so that it be pure JavaScript.

Comment: if it meets your needs please mark as correct answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use below step.

1. Create one `HTML Div`
2. Make that div as `Visible false` or `display:none`
3. Set height and width for Div. make it `screen.Width` and `screen.Height`
4. when user click on `Checkbox` - set that div `visible=true` or `display:block` for 5 Seconds.
5. After 5 Seconds make it invisible.

Comment: Ultimately you should make one `div` and it should act as `Model Popup`  for 5 Second.